# Compiling Realm project with Jack compiler

Tags: java, android, realm

How can I use realm.io with Java 1.8?

For Android with Java 1.8 you need to use jack. The combination of the Android realm gradle plugin and jack seems not to work. Because after I added

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

to my *app.gradle* file, I get

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find property 'options' on task ':app:compileProdDebugJavaWithJack'.
```

Does someone know how to get work it together? Why isn't there a *normal* dependency?

Comment: See discussion on https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2630

Answer (score 2):

At the moment that's **not possible**.
Jack doesn't produce .class files which are required for Realm to deal with proxy classes.

But people work on this so in future that *might be possible*.
Track these issues for details:

- Realm [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3038) on Github.
- Jack [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210730) on b.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use retrolambda if you're using Jack to use Java 8 features like lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround. Right now in my company's project, we extract realm to another module and setup realm there, then open jack in 'app' module is fine.