# Trying to use Java 1.8 only for one external dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

After adding a third party library I got the PARSE ERROR: unsupported class file version 52.0 after including the dependency. I have found similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project). The solution in the link provide suggest to include in the gradle file the following:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

The problem is that the dependency is using 1.8. So, I have tried to use 1.8 for the entire project by adding Jack as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004069/errorjack-is-required-to-support-java-8-language-features). However, I am also using Realm that can't be used with java 8 as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746452/compiling-realm-project-with-jack-compiler).

Is there any way to use 1.8 only for the dependency I want to include and use 1.7 in the rest of the project?

I am quite new and I don't know if this is possible. I have checked around, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Try using Retrolambda. It is a Gradle Plugin which can translate Java 8 source code to Java 7 source code, however it can't translate everything, for example static methods in interfaces can't be translated to Java 7, so try Retrolambda - if that works you are in luck - otherwise you can't really fix this issue. Then the only option that is left is to find a Java 7 version of that library or compile the library yourself after migrating it to Java 7 (as long as it is open source).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am going to try and see if it works.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have tried to use Retrolambda in a clean project, however, I have not been able to sync the gradle. I got Error:Cannot get property 'destinationDir' on null object.